# SQL - sum function

Tags: sql, apache-spark, sum, apache-spark-sql

I have problems transforming following:

```
OPP_auftag      sum_correct     sum_incorrect
---------------------------------------------------------------
yes             770             1324
no              4512            79
```

into:

```
 OPP_auftrag        sum_complete
---------------------------------------
yes                 5282
no                  1403
```

Please don´t get confused with the OPP_auftrag 'yes' and 'no'. I want to SUM the column 'sum_correct' (770+4512) in the row yes and the column 'sum_complete'
and the same with the sum_incorrect into the row 'no'.
Any quick suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably need to explain why you want to do this. There are queries that will give you this result, but it isn't clear why the sum of sum_correct maps to 'yes' when its data is in records that map to both 'yes' and 'no'. The suggestions that will give you the result you're looking for will be unlikely to reflect the logic you have in your head for why this should be the result. Are OPP_auftag and OPP_auftrag different fields or is it a typo? Can you describe your data model?

Comment: I implemented a random forest algorithm to predict an order...I had already some data with the value 'order' and 'no_order'...so I tried to let the random forest algorithm predict it, this was the result the random forest algorithm counted 770 correct fields where I had 'order' and he counted 4512 correct fields where I had the field 'no_order' the second code is the conclution: he predicted 5282 rows right (order or no_order) and he predicted 1403 rows false...It´s hard to describe for someone whose first languauge is not english, but I already found a sulution down below.

Comment: btw, I can´t understand why I get a down-vote for my question. I had problems solving this issue and I couldn´t find something on the internet to this topic :( Seems that not every user knows that also amateurs are using this website to ask questions....

Comment: I'm not sure why you got the downvote. It wasn't me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OPP_auftrag , CASE OPP_auftrag WHEN 'yes' THEN (SELECT SUM(sum_correct) FROM OPP_auftrag ) 
ELSE (SELECT SUM(sum_incorrect) FROM OPP_auftrag) END AS sum_complete
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY OPP_auftrag
```

Comment: Thank you, I just had to edit a few names: SELECT OPP_auftrag , CASE OPP_auftrag WHEN 'yes' THEN (SELECT SUM(sum_correct) FROM OPP_auftrag ) 
ELSE (SELECT SUM(sum_incorrect) FROM OPP_auftrag) END AS sum_complete
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY OPP_auftrag

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum_correct + sum_incoorect FROM yourtable WHERE OPP_auftag = 'yes'
UNION ALL 
SELECT sum(sum_incoorect) FROM yourtable
```